# New line charactor in ie

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, newline

I have the following html

```
<label>Hello\r\nUsername</label>

<textarea></textarea>
```

After page load i want to set the content of the `label` to `textarea`

normally

```
$("textarea").val($("label").html()); // or may be $("label").text();
```

will set the content to the textarea including new lines.It works fine in FF,But not in IE.

It looke like IE is losing the new line info.

How can i solve this ? Please help me.

Comment: Are you actually typing out the escapechars in the HTMLcode or is it just to make a point?

Comment: Is the `\r\n` typed out in the HTML or do you have an actual linebreak in the code?

Comment: Its just to make sure that there is a line break.

Comment: I guess \r\n won't work with HTML. You have to use <br/>.

Comment: I made a fiddle to use, http://jsfiddle.net/xdZ7X/. Fails in IE8, works in IE9.

Comment: if i used `<br />` then i will get a new line on `label` , which i dont want ,it works well in `FF` but not in IE.Yes \r\n wont work in html but it will work with textarea.

Comment: @HenrikAmmer Thanks ..but i need this work in IE too,

Comment: After a [small search on Google](https://www.google.se/search?q=ie8+html+linebreak+javascript) I found out that it isn't possible in IE with a version less then 9 since its a built in problem. Check http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0226430/innerHtmlQuirk.html for reference. In all, IE<9 removes all white-space in any DOM element except `pre` and `textarea`.

Comment: Thank you very much , But i manages it with `<br/>` as per your suggestion, and it works great.Please make this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a small search on Google I found out that it isn't possible in IE with a version less then 9 since its a built in problem. Check web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0226430/innerHtmlQuirk.html for reference. In all, IE<9 removes all white-space in any DOM element except pre and textarea.